# What does this mysql syntax do

Tags: mysql

`SELECT @no:=0`

What does the above code do?

I found it in a very long query, looking like this:

```
SELECT t1.a, t2.a, ....... FROM table t1, (SELECT @no:=0) t2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It will cross join @no with Table t1

Comment: `@no` is supposed to be a table? What is `:=0` ?

Comment: It is a way to assign value to variable in MySQL.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba32e4/1 Check demo link

Comment: Is @no used anywhere in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In below query, @no is a variable of a MySQL and by using `:=0` it is assigned a value `0`.

`SELECT @no:=0`

**Explanation:**

**User-defined variables** (prefixed with @):

You can access any user-defined variable without declaring it or initializing it. If you refer to a variable that has not been initialized, it has a value of NULL and a type of string.

```
SELECT @var_any_var_name
```

You can initialize a variable using SET or SELECT statement:

```
SET @start = 1, @finish = 10;
```

or

```
SELECT @start := 1, @finish := 10;
```

For more info on User-Defined variables follow the below link:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> In `Select @no:=0` you are defining a variable with value 0

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`a` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`a`)
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4),
    (5)
;

SELECT t1.a, @no FROM table1 t1, 
(SELECT @no:=0) t2
```

**Output**

```
a   @no
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   0
```

Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba32e4/1